# How to generate double tallgrass in Minecraft superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create a superflat world with a layer of bedrock, 62 dirt, 1 layer grass blocks, then a layer of double tallgrass on top of that - in a plains biome with no decorations or structures.

I'm wondering first of all what the code would be to create this, as I *think* I've written it right, (the superflat customization screen shows that it will generate my double tallgrass and everything else) but Minecraft crashes every time I try to go into the new world, so I don't know what it looks like...

Secondly, I need to know if this is actually possible - is Minecraft crashing because I wrote the code wrong, or because I CAN'T generate double tallgrass?

Here's the code I wrote to try and make this work:

`3;1*minecraft:bedrock,62*minecraft:dirt,1*minecraft:grass,1*minecraft:double_plant:2;1;`

Comment: You generated a map full of half of a double plant. Of course it's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the bottom half of the tall grass generating, but not the upper half, so when the grass updates, it realizes it needs to break, and that propagates endlessly ad crashium.

Here's a preset code for your superflat world that has both the lower and upper halves of the tall grass:

```
3;1*minecraft:bedrock,62*minecraft:dirt,1*minecraft:grass,1*minecraft:double_plant:2,1*minecraft:double_plant:10;1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't realise my map was trying to create half plants...

Comment: @ToomanyBees Make sure to mark the answer as correct so he gets the credit he deserves.